Is there any better way to write this piece of code?
I am a beginner in this, I was curious if i can write the below code
more efficiently.
I can't use loops or conditional statements, just logical operators.
        double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        boolean check = a * a + b * b == c * c || a * a + c * c == b * b
                || b * b + c * c == a * a;
        StdOut.println(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && check);

I tried the below code but there was a problem that even if the value (a,b,c) was negative, it kept resulting in true for this command-line argument:(-3 4 -5) idk why.
        double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        boolean check = a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a * a + b * b == c * c || a * a + c * c == b * b
                || b * b + c * c == a * a;
        StdOut.println(check);


About the efficiency part of the question, let the compiler worry about that, aim for maximum readability instead.

For future reference, you can web search with "Java operator precedence". Here is one result: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Aside from the accuracy of the code, it's just five lines, and you only have significant input to one of those. There's nothing you can do that will make any significant difference. If you had more code (50 lines? 500 lines? more?) that might be different.

theoretical improvements: (first solution) do the multiplications only once (a = a*a or aa = a*a). Also note that second solution, once corrected, is (theoretically) better than first since no multiplication will be done if some value is negative (easier test) -- but the difference is negligible (compared to parseDouble for example)

Due to operator precedence, this expression:
a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a * a + b * b == c * c || a * a + c * c == b * b || b * b + c * c == a * a

Is treated as:
(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a * a + b * b == c * c) || (a * a + c * c == b * b) || (b * b + c * c == a * a)

So it is the OR of three conditions. That's not your intended grouping, so you have to add parentheses manually.
a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && (a * a + b * b == c * c || a * a + c * c == b * b || b * b + c * c == a * a)

